# How to clarify what my apps icons are - Android

Tags: android, icons, android-drawable

I have 2 questions,

Okay so I have read online what sizes I should make my app icons for certain size phone screens. I know how to clarify what the launcher Icon is for my app with this code,

```
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
```

My app image is 72px x 72px. So its placed in the drawable-hdpi folder. Then I have a 36px x 36px icon for low density screens which is placed in the drawable-ldpi folder. So, for the 36px x 36px icon, should it be saved in the drawable-ldpi folder as icon? Cause wouldn't this cause an error because 2 files will be named the same thing?

Second question is my app launcher icon is saved in the drawable-hdpi folder. I read online that I also need an action bar and status bar icon, both have to be 36px x 36px. Where do I save these files at? In the drawable-hdpi file for high resolution screens I assume, but what do I name them? Do I have to clarify them in the android manifest file? How do I do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better if you forget `px` when talking about Android drawables and think in `dp` instead. Launcher icon is 48x48dp, so (48px on mdpi, 72px on hdpi, etc.)

> So, for the 36px x 36px icon, should it be saved in the drawable-ldpi folder as icon?

Yes.

> Cause wouldn't this cause an error because 2 files will be named the same thing?

No. Android nicely handles same resource for different configurations even if you have folder with name `drawable-large-land-fr-xhdpi` or something like this. It tries to take the best match from its configuration.

> I read online that I also need an action bar and status bar icon, both have to be 36px x 36px.

It's always good to provide source, which seems to be giving false statements. You can [read on Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html) that action bar icons have to be 32x32dp and notification 24x24dp. And you don't need them if you don't use them.

> Where do I save these files at? In the drawable-hdpi file for high resolution screens I assume, but what do I name them?

You can name them anything you like (you don't need to name your app icon as `icon.png`).

> Do I have to clarify them in the android manifest file?

No. You put them when you use them. For action bar icons that would probably be in `menu.xml`.